$\text{AM-GM}$ inequality doubt

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $(2^{1+x}+2^{1−x}), f(x)$ and $(3^x+3^{−x})$ are in A.P. Then, what is the minimum value of $f(x)$

The solution given in the book is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{2^{1−x}+2^{1+x}+3^x+3^{−x}}{2} \\
&=\frac{2(2^{−x}+2^x)+(3^x+3^{−x})}{2} \\
&=\frac{(2^{−x}+2^x)+(2^x+2^{−x})}{2}.
\end{align}$$
Using $\text{AM} \geq \text{GM}$, $f(x) \geq 3$.
But, when I did it:
$$\frac{2^{1-x} +2^{1+x} + 3^x +3^{-x}}{4} \geq (2^2)^{1/4} = 2^{1/2},$$
thus $f(x) \geq 2 \sqrt 2$.
Please could someone explain what I did wrong? Is there any property of the $\text{AM-GM}$ inequality that I am missing?

This is difficult to read. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The solution in the book reaches
$f(x) = (2\times(2^{-x} + 2^{x}) + (3^{-x} + 3^x))/2$ .
Using the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality twice gives $2^{-x} + 2^x \ge 2 \sqrt{2^{-x} \times 2^x} = 2$ and $3^{-x} + 3^x \ge 2 \sqrt{3^{-x} \times 3^x} = 2$, with equality holding in both inequalities when $x = 0$. Thus
$$f(x) \ge \frac{2 \times 2 + 2}{2} = 3 = f(0).$$
Your inequality
$$\frac{2^{1-x} + 2^{1+x} + 3^{-x} + 3^x}{4} \ge \sqrt[4]{2^{1-x} \times 2^{1+x} \times 3^{-x} \times 3^x} = \sqrt{2}$$
is also correct. Note, however, that equality cannot hold, since there is no solution to $2^{1-x} = 2^{1 + x} = 3^{-x} = 3^x$. So in fact $\frac{2^{1-x} + 2^{1+x} + 3^{-x} + 3^x}{4} > \sqrt{2}$, or
$$f(x) > 2\sqrt{2} \approx 2.8 (\text{to 1 decimal place})$$
So your lower bound is correct, but weak.
